# Get mode from list of pipe-separated digits

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a character variable containing codes discribing project characteristics. Looking like this:

```
[1] "151"     "510|130|130"     "311|110" "140"     "160|160"     "160|160|130"
[7] "160"     "160"     "160"      "151"     "151"     "160|110"
```

I need to extract the main characteristic of the project, meaning the code that dominates. In case there is no dominating code I choose the first. resulting in:

```
[1] "151"     "130"     "311"      "140"     "160"     "160"
[7] "160"     "160"     "160"      "151"     "151"     "160"
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share the code to construct your vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` to split your vector and use `collapse::fmode` to get the value that "dominate" (a so-called statistical mode), and the first value if there is a tie (which is the default behavior of `fmode`):

```r
x <- c("151", "510|130|130", "311|110")
as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(x, "\\|"), collapse::fmode))
#[1] 151 130 311
```

Other ways of making a `mode` function, which is not directly implemented in base R, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/how-to-find-the-statistical-mode).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option without using additional packages

```
> x <- c("151", "510|130|130", "311|110", "160|160|130", "160|110")

> d <- table(rev(stack(setNames(strsplit(x, "|", fixed = TRUE), seq_along(x)))))

> as.numeric(colnames(d)[max.col(d)])
[1] 151 130 110 160 110
```